# Kafka join after rekey - Scaling

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm having redundant apps that needs to consume two streams (let's say topic *foo* and *bar*) and take action on *bar.value* when *foo.key* matches *bar.value.matching_key*. I want the action to be performed only once.

I would like confirmations/insights on these:

- It seems that joined topics need to be copartitioned. However, we are not the owner of the *bar* topic. How can I ensure the rekey table has the same number of partitions than the *foo* topic? My assumption is that we need to same app to consume *bar* and rekey it in another stream with the key matching *foo*.
- Assuming the rekey in topic *bar-byfookey* from previous question: how does Kafka ensure that every partition assigned to an instance of the app is the same for both topics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Streams API, the library would create the re-keying topic automatically if you set the join key in your code. For example:

```java
KStream fooStream = builder.stream("foo");
KTable barTable = builder.table("bar");
fooStream.selectKey(/*set "bar" key*/).join(barTable,...);
```

This would be executed as:

```java
fooStream.selectKey(/*set "bar" key*/).to("rekey-foo");
KStream rekeyFooStream = builder.stream("rekey-foo");
rekeyFooStream.join(barTable,...);
```

For the partition assignment: Kafka Streams does not use the default partition assigner from the consumer, but a custom implementation that ensures the topic partitions a assigned correctly.

Comment: Interesting! So no need to manually create a temporary topic since it actually is the repartition topic. However, how can I ensure that the repartition topic is copartitioned with the topic I want to join with? Does the Streams API handle this for me? If so, what happens when the topic I join with alter in a way that copartitioned isn't satisfied anymore?

Comment: Well. You gave me the answer and I wasn't event able to see it. I get that I need to use the `to` function to push into a topic where I have control over the partitions. I'll play with the solution shortly. Thanks Matthias!

Comment: Streams will create the topic with the correct number of partitions using the default producer partitioner (you can specify a different partitioner if necessary, too). For changing the number of partitions of the input topic (or changing the partitioning): this will break the application and is not supported.